# Why are bit fields limited to member variables?

Tags: c++, bit-fields

I just learned about bit fields and now I am wondering why they can only be applied to member variables, rather than global or function level variables.

for something like

```
int main(){
    unsigned u : 3;
}
```

I get

```
error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    unsigned u : 3
```

So, why do bit fields not work for variables other than members?

Comment: I guess it will work only with struct.

Comment: @fquinner That one's about C, this one's about C++, but the same rationale probably covers both languages. Tricky.

Comment: There's no separate rationale for C++. C++ inherited them from C, and the changes are merely practical (i.e. a bitfield member can be `private` in C++, but that's not a very intentional change from C. It follows from the rule that all members obey access specifications)